# Android UI Repaint / Refresh issue with SwitchCompat and Seekbar

Tags: android, user-interface, refresh, lag

Does anyone have experience of the following issue:

> UI Repaint / Refresh issue with the following 2 components

- android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
  toggling the switch will alternate between 2 different views being visible / invisible
- android.widget.SeekBar
  sliding the seekbar will result in a viewpager view being shown

> Description; when I slide either of the above widgets in any direction:

- the thumbnail does not slide across into the intended position
- UI changes triggered by the Switch do not take place

> However:

- the SwitchCompat's onCheckedChanged method is definitely called; print statements / toast confirm this
- the Seekbar's onStopTrackingTouch method is definitely called; print statements / toast confirm this

> Upon further Investigation

- pulling the sliding drawer across, results in the widget redrawing its state correctly.
- looks like invalidate / refresh is not getting called properly, but the navigationdrawer enforces this

> I have tried it on 4 different devices...

Samsung S5: Android 5.0.1 (API 21) - NOT OK
Samsung S7: Android 7.0 (API 24) - NOT OK
Samsung S3 Mini: Android 4.2.2 (API 17) - OK
Samsung Tablet: Android 4.1.2 (API 16) - OK

> Here is a summary of my setup

IDE: Android Studio
Gradle Excerpt:

```
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Still having this issue.... can anyone help please...?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you extend AppCompatActivity